# IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, postman, iis-10, .net-4.8

I am trying to run a web API application on my local machine. When I run the project it is working without problem, but when I try for a post request [it counts like this but not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhbKB.png)

From postman, I get this error [not returning any result from my post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWKyJ.png.

Do you have any solution to this kind of problem?

I am trying to use my post method and get response.

Comment: You probably just have and incorrect URL. My guess is that it should be http://localhost:some-port/api/controller-name/authenticate, where "some-port" and "controller-name" needs to be provided by you.

Comment: could you please try to host it over Local IIS first and then connect website to Visual Studio to debug and to know where exactly is the issue,

Comment: and could you please confirm if this is happening with this url or with every hot either GET or POST or POST only?

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.